# MySQL update on select json extract

Tags: mysql, sql, json, replace, sql-update

I have the following query which looks for the string `www.website.com\/content` in a LONGTEXT column called `content`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT json_extract(content, '$.body') b FROM `blocks`) AS new
WHERE b LIKE '%www.website.com\/content%'
```

How do I update the returned data from the select query above to replace the `www.website.com\/content` string with `www.website.com`?

I have tried this also:

```
UPDATE `blocks`
SET content = REPLACE(content, 'www.website.com\/content', 'www.website.com')
WHERE content LIKE '%www.website.com\/content%'
```

But this doesn't return any results for the LIKE condition.

The data in the `content` column would look like this:

```
{"body":"<p>Some HTML</p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.website.com\/content\/grand-pianos\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\">grand pianos<\/a>"}
```

Comment: the update cpommand is not the problem see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aafba4c1363351eab8c563a3fa2d01f2)*  please check if if you safe update mode configured

Comment: it works on longtext too https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c98254d353d89e1168ca50f4eca8be01